# Rails scoping on children method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to scope on children methods.

#### Parent.rb

```
has_many :children
```

#### Child.rb

```
belongs_to :Parent

def mymethod
  returns true or false
end

attributes :valid
```

Now I want to find all parents who have loans where `mymethod` and the :valid attribute == true
so something like

```
Item.where(loans.where(valid: true, mymethod: true), true)
```

Comment: my method is a method not an active record attribute correct?

Comment: can this method by any ways be calculated from the database? if not we'll need to fetch all record that match the other condition then filter them from the array.

Comment: Im afraid not, its a method that checks if a certain date has passed

Comment: and this date has nothing to do with a child's attributes?

Comment: also explain the relation between child vs parent and item vs loan..

Comment: could you add the `mymethod` code, it might help me think of something.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need it's this:

```
Item.joins(:children).where children: { valid: true, mymethod: true }
```

Comment: The problem is that `mymethod` isn't an attribute to query, or at least that's what I understood from the comments

Comment: Like Mohammed says, this will give you an "unknown column mymethod" error

Comment: In this case, you can do persistent on DB this field with before_save callback method.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but mymethod checks if a Date has passed. So today it might be true but tomorrow it might be false without there ever beeing a save. So a callback wont solve this problem.

Comment: You can use `where("stored_date < current_date")`